# Rails: Why does Rake require the Mysql root user?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

I get the following error when I attempt to run a RAKE task:

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My `database.yml` file looks like this:

```
production:
  [...]
  database: <some_database_name>
  username: <a_non_root_user>
  password: <password_for_above_non_root_user>
```

The conflict is, as you can see:

- I use a non-root user to access the database, but
- Rake wants to use the root user (for a reason I don't see)

Does this mean that I should use the root user in the `database.yml` configuration? (Seems against security logic to me.) What is the best solution here?

Comment: you have set up your production user, but are you passing RAILS_ENV while executing rake? i.e. bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: @DanielLutz - Ooops, that is of course it. Please add it as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the environment to production.

i.e.:

```
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: how about when you are working under dev? or how about if you just want to deploy changes to staging? and so on? (if you are not working under production this simply will crash)

Answer (score -1):

Above answer did not worked in my case, the question is really generic so ill add my case, besides the fact running against production could be really dangerous if you don't know what you are doing....handle carefully.

Instead what i did to solve this issue was just to update

config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  charset: utf8mb4
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: your_password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: your_database_name
  host: <%= Settings.db.default.host %>
  port: <%= Settings.db.default.port %>
```

So that way your bundle/rake task will load these values and dont ask them at runtime...also remeber you are in the right folder path (root path of your ruby on rails project)

Hope this helps!

I ran into this issue and for me was precisely this (facepalm) i completely forgot about my config file :P

Another option is to use

```
  username: <%= Settings.db.default.username %>
  password: <%= Settings.db.default.password %>
```

So just keep in mind you need to setup these values as OS variables